# Who Are the Most Prominent Modern Socialist Thinkers?

Tags: marxism, economics, democracy, socialism, liberalism

Who Are The Ten Most Prominent Modern Socialist Thinkers? (Big Tent: Social Democrats, Socialists, Communists, etc. are all acceptable).

Comment: See [21st-century communist theorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st-century_communist_theorists).

Comment: Istvan Meszaros was an important thinker. He died in 2017. You can read a little about him here.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istv%C3%A1n_M%C3%A9sz%C3%A1ros_(professor)

Comment: "Modern" means roughly "since the Renaissance". Do you actually mean that, or do you mean "contemporary"?

Answer (score 2):

Modern but not necessarily still living (L):

> Noam Chomsky (L)
>
> Terry Eagleton (L)
>
> Bertell Ollman (L)
>
> Perry Anderson (L)
>
> Chantal Mouffe (L)
>
> John E. Roemer (L)
>
> Eric Hobsbawm (d. 2012)
>
> G.A. Cohen (d. 2009)
>
> Ralph Miliband (d. 1994)
>
> E.P. Thompson (d. 1993)

Comment: At least Chomsky and Hobsbawm despise the "postmodernists" as impostors. Who else?

Comment: Thanks for comment. The question was not framed in terms of  'modern *and* anti-postmodern'. I would have answered differently, of course, if it had.   Do you share Chomsky's and Hobsbawm's repudiation of postmodernism ?

Comment: I live in a country that needs serious left intellectuals. "If they're all screaming postmodern bullshit, then it's gone!", as Chomsky said. Postmodernism is a poison that takes a few serious issues, inflates them to extremes, repudiates (to use your word) science and objectivity, in the end creating crowds of young people who scream postmodernist jargon while not being able to investigate seriously most issues we need to. People unable to interpret a simple Cartesian graphic! There are people who see it, people who don't see it, and people who don't want to see it. Which of them are you?